# How do I invoke OnActionExecuting when I call another controller's ActionResult function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 MVC projects.  There is a common page that I want to reference directly instead of having to re-write.  I'm doing so like this:

```
public ActionResult test()
{
    OldController.Controllers.PatronController temp = new OldController.Controllers.PatronController();

    return temp.Index();
}
```

The problem is, in "OldController" there is some functionality that get set in the OnActionExecuting function.  When I call the function like I'm doing above, OnActionExecuting isn't being called.

How can I share the common page between the two projects (so I can return it `OnActionExecuting`?

Comment: it's a well thought out question. the more I think about it, the more impressed I am with it. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you want to keep navigation consistent in each project and still re-use the core functionality.

For that reason, I recommend:

1) creating a 3rd MVC Project with an Action Partial (Partial with Action Method -- and Controller).

2) Add a reference for your new MVC project to your 2 primary MVC projects.

3) In each of your primary MVC projects, create Views that render your Action Partial within a View.

Comment: Ameen mentioned this as well, and using this method I was able to achieve what I wanted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a third project that is a class library and inside that library create a ControllerBase class that has the common functionality between the two controllers and in each project derive from that controller class.